# getting the task list under a particular group using JBPM 6.1

Tags: jbpm, taskservice

I'm a newbie to JBPM and having trouble getting the task list under a particular group using JBPM 6.1
But I can get the tasks under a user by simply using

```
taskService.getTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwner("username", "en-UK");
```

But the TaskService doesn't have a method to get tasks of a particular group. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the user group call backs that will inject the user groups and take those into account. Take a look at the official docs